# Multiset questions requested

Tags: combinatorics

I am in need of more multiset questions. Would anyone have any combinatiorics questions that deal with multisets? I've been look around on Google, but haven't really found any.

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ should contain some exercises you can do...

Comment: I would rather not purchase a book.

Comment: The book is available from his website.

Comment: @Bulberage : Ah, the vol. 1 second edition's manuscript pdf is available! Even if it may not be the same as the final version, good enough to read. Thanks!

Comment: @Ozera : Do you want only questions or along with solutions?

Comment: @gar Enumerative Combinatorics contains solutions.

Comment: @Bulberage : That's true, but I wanted to know whether the OP was asking for open problems.

Comment: @gar Open problems meaning currently unsolved? I do not think I am ready for those. I was looking for problems which had solutions. However a user does not post the solution, I do not mind.

Comment: @Ozera : Okay, I shared two problems which I remember.

Answer (score 1):

These two problems and their solutions have amazed me, and have been discussed in MSE a while back. (wordings may be different)

Please forgive me if you already know these. It may help if you share the problems you already know.

1. Given the multiset `[a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,e,e,e]`, how many permutations are possible such that no two adjacent letters are the same?

   (Ans: $26008189608$)
2. Bins are labelled and placed like this: `[a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,e,e,e]`.
   There is one ball in each bin, also with the same labels but different colors (imagine it to be like a suit of cards). In how many ways can we rearrange the balls so that each bin must have a ball with different label?

   (Ans: $434110803856588800$)

Comment: Would you happen to have links for these two problems?

Comment: No, I did not bookmark the questions..

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I'll have to see if I can find them.

Comment: Okay, please comment the links if you find them.